# How to plot different style of faults using matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, geology

I want to plot faults with different styles such as normal, revers and strike-slip. As any of them has their own styles in geological maps, I have to plot them with a unique symbols. Up until now I just plot them using the following code:

```
import pylab as plt

fault = [[]]

with open('strike_slip.dat') as f:

    for l in f:

        if l.strip() and '--' not in l and '#' not in l:

            val = l.split()

            fault[-1].append((float(val[0]),float(val[1])))

        if '---' in l:

            fault.append([])


ax = plt.subplot(111)

for i in fault:

    x = [_[0] for _ in i]
    y = [_[1] for _ in i]

    ax.plot(x,y,color='k')

ax.set_xlim(50,52)
ax.set_ylim(28,30)

plt.show()
```

and this this the result:
[image: fault_plot]

I want to plot some symbols to show different types of faults (normal, revers, strike-slip).